# Laravel 5.5 eager loading throws error - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I see a lot of people are having trouble with eager loading and Laravel, and I'm one of them too.
I'm getting the error: Trying to get property of non-object

**SOLUTION:** I needed to include `public $incrementing = false;` in my models. See expanded answer at bottom

I've looked at other stack overflow answers, but none of them have solved this issue: here's **all** my code

My 2 migration files

**create_authors_table**

```
<?php

# database/migrations/1970_01_01_000001_create_authors_table

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAuthorsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('author_id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary('author_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('authors');
    }
}
```

**create_books_table**

```
<?php

# database/migrations/1970_01_01_000002_create_books_table

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('book_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('author_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('author_id')->references('author_id')->on('authors');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

Next, here's my routes

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php

# routes/web.php
Route::get('/books', 'BookController@index');
```

I have 2 models

**Models/Author.php**

```
<?php

# app/Models/Author.php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Author extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'author_id';

    public function book()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Book');
    }
}
```

**Models/Book.php**

```
<?php

# app/Models/Book.php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'book_id';

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author', 'author_id');
    }
}
```

Here's my **BookController**

```
<?php

# app/Http/Controllers/BookController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Book;

class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $books = Book::with('author')->get();


        $results = [];
        foreach ($books as $book) {
            $result = new \stdClass();
            $result->title = $book->title;
            $result->author_first_name = $book->author->first_name;
            $result->author_last_name = $book->author->last_name;
            $results[] = $result;
        }

        dd($results);
    }
}
```

**Here's some test data to fill the database with:**

```
insert into authors (author_id, first_name, last_name, created_at) 
values 
(
  'ceefb81f-48bb-ff07-1002-27fd8b7272b4', 'Charles', 'Coal', '2018-02-11 00:00:00'
);

INSERT INTO books (book_id, title, author_id, created_at)
VALUES 
(
  'a4e58f2a-36f5-f2fb-960c-c60e2689b337', 'Killing Coal', 'ceefb81f-48bb-ff07-1002-27fd8b7272b4',
  '2018-02-11 00:00:00'
),
(
  'a4e58f2a-36f5-f2fb-960c-c60e2689b338', 'Cleaning Coal', 'ceefb81f-48bb-ff07-1002-27fd8b7272b4',
  '2018-02-11 00:00:01'
),
(
  'a4e58f2a-36f5-f2fb-960c-c60e2689b339', 'Using Coal', 'ceefb81f-48bb-ff07-1002-27fd8b7272b4',
  '2018-02-11 00:00:02'
);
```

I've turned on logging in MySQL and can see that 2 queries are being run

```
# turn on logging by running the following in MySQL
SET GLOBAL log_output = "FILE";
SET GLOBAL general_log_file = "/tmp/mysql.logfile.log";
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

And here's the output of the MySQL log file

```
2018-02-11T18:52:21.426064Z   262 Prepare   select * from `books`
2018-02-11T18:52:21.426348Z   262 Execute   select * from `books`
2018-02-11T18:52:21.426539Z   262 Close stmt    
2018-02-11T18:52:21.430560Z   262 Prepare   select * from `authors` where `authors`.`author_id` in (?)
2018-02-11T18:52:21.430689Z   262 Execute   select * from `authors` where `authors`.`author_id` in ('ceefb81f-48bb-ff07-1002-27fd8b7272b4')
```

But, for some reason, the relationships aren't being associated

**SOLUTION**
Since, I'm using GUIDs instead of auto-incrementing integers, I had to tell Eloquent that the primary keys are not auto-incrementing. Laravel behind the scenes was trying to cast my GUID to an integer.

```
<?php
# app/Models/Book.php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'book_id';

    # HAD TO ADD THIS
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author', 'author_id');
    }
}
```

**app/Models/Author**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Author extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'author_id';

    # HAD TO ADD THIS
    public $incrementing  = false;

    public function book()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Book');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For `Book` model you need define third parameter `book_id`

```
public function author()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author', 'book_id', 'author_id');
}
```

> If your parent model does not use id as its primary key, or you wish
>   to join the child model to a different column, you may pass a third
>   argument to the belongsTo method specifying your parent table's custom
>   key

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but, I get the following error if I add the 3rd parameter `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'authors.book_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from authors where authors.book_id in (ceefb81f-48bb-ff07-1002-27fd8b7272b4)`

Comment: ah! yrv16! You're brilliant. You had the 2 keys transposed: the function Book::author()  should be: `return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Author', 'book_id', 'author_id');`

Comment: no! It's not working if there's more than 1 author :-(  the query being run against MySQL is `select * from authors where authors.author_id in (0, 39)`

Comment: @KearneyTaaffe Your problem is that you use  `$table->string('author_id');` and `$table->string('book_id');` instead of `$table->increments('author_id');` and `$table->increments('book_id');`. Use integer keys for relation between tables.

Comment: it's better when creating APIs to use GUIDs instead of integers. Less hackable, and that's been the general consensus for the past couple of years. 

if I'm facing a limitation of Eloquent, there's got to be a way around it.

Comment: @KearneyTaaffe If you use `belongsTo` it means that one book belongs to only one author if you want one book can belongs to many authors you need use many to many relation. In Laravel it has name `belongsToMany`

Comment: no, a book belongs to 1 author. What I was saying didn't work is if there's more than 1 author in the database, sorry for the confusion. With more than 1 author in the database, I get the same error, "Error trying to get property of non object". The query being run starts using some weird random numbers - that's why I published the query being run in the database

Comment: @KearneyTaaffe By the way you also need $table->primary('book_id'); for `CreateBooksTable` migration.

Comment: yeah, good catch. So, I found the solution: I need to put `public $incrementing = false;` in my models. That has solved the issue

Comment: @KearneyTaaffe I am glad that you found solution.